# What are the best practices when launching a smart contract protocol on multiple networks/chains?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, polygon, wrapped-tokens

Hi I have some questions on protocols that launch on multiple networks/chains.

For example, Aave originally launched on the Ethereum network but now is also on networks like Polygon and Avalanche. To facilitate activity on Aave, two ERC20 tokens are utilized in Aave's smart contract, aToken and AAVE.

Some questions on launching on multiple networks/chains are:

1. When we want to launch a protocol on Polygon that already exists on say Ethereum, do we just re-deploy the same contract on Polygon?
2. If the protocol utilizes native token in the smart contracts, do we re-deploy the ERC20 token as well? Or require users to bridge their native token from Ethereum to the new Polygon network as a wrapped token? - if so, is doubling the token supply a concern for protocols that had a fixed supply when it was just on a single network?
3. In general, what are the best practices when a protocol is to be launched on multiple networks/chains?